# Which of the following polynomials has the greatest real root?

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, roots

> Which of the following polynomials has the greatest real root? $\textbf{(A) }   x^{19}+2018x^{11}+1   \qquad$        $\textbf{(B) }   x^{17}+2018x^{11}+1   \qquad$    $\textbf{(C) }   x^{19}+2018x^{13}+1   \qquad$   $\textbf{(D) }  x^{17}+2018x^{13}+1 \qquad$  $\textbf{(E) }   2019x+2018$

To 'find' real roots we can set each expression $A$ to $E$ equal to $0$, which makes it pretty clear that the value $x$ must be negative (for else they'd be huge positive numbers), but also pretty small, since the terms with variable $x$ in each expression (despite their coefficients) must equal $-1$, for (A) to (D). $x=-1$ or $x=0$ will not work, however, so we need $x$ to be $-1<x<0$.

For (E) we can just solve for $x$ from $2019x + 2018=0$, but that gives an $x$ pretty close to $-1$ and I need to see if there are any greater roots (i.e. closer to $0$).

However, now I'm stuck and don't know how to move on. Any help would really be appreciated!

Comment: ah...! for some reason, I couldn't find them before. Thank you for the links.